# How can I remove empty lines from the content of an environment?

Tags: amsmath, environments, paragraphs, xstring

I'm using this equation command to reduce typing when creating aligned equation blocks. I would like to use empty lines within this command to help structure my LaTeX source. Currently, those cause an error because display equation environments don't support them. How can I remove all empty lines from `#1`, but keep the `\\`, before forwarding the content to the amsmath environment?

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\eq}[1]{\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}#1\end{aligned}\end{equation}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\eq{
z &= f(y) \\
y &= f(x) \\

x &= 5
}
\end{document}
```

Error message:

```
Runaway argument?

\begin {aligned} z &= f(y) \\ y &= f(x) \\ 
! Paragraph ended before \gather was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.14 }

I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.
```

Comment: All math display ens does not support blank lines. And btw don't do this it is waste of your time using it as a macro. If you what to combine gather and aligned do it as an environment, use it as a macro makes the code much much harder to read and to work with. Trust me, ice been there and learned my lesson. Instead look into how your editor can save you time when typing.

Comment: @daleif Thanks for your comment. I'm aware that the math display environments don't support blank lines. That's why I want to remove them from the input argument before passing the content into the amsmath environment. I appreciate your advice but I've been using the above macro for a while now and it has saved me a lot of typing in documents with many display equations. Readability can be important, but it's also a trade-off.

Comment: `\noindent\begin{gather}` is wrong and will generate poor output in most cases. You have not shown how you are using this but there should not be a blank line before display math.

Comment: The `\eq` environment above simply lets me put empty lines before and after the environment in the TeX source without them causing paragraphs in the output PDF. This lets me structure my document with empty lines and quickly move around using Vim's `[` and `]`. I appreciate the advice, although I think this is not directly relevant for my question.

Comment: also you are using `gather` with a single row which is also discouraged it would be better to use  `\[..\]` as `gather` can not use the short display skips.

Comment: That's interesting. Do you know a reference where I can learn more about the difference between the two? I sometimes get the impression that learning details about LaTeX and its packages often happens by chance through word of mouth.

Comment: no sorry, `\eq` does not prevent a blank line before the equation producing incorrect output.

Comment: Then you'll just learn the hard way. With almost 20 years of experience editing other people's latex code I'm glad I don't have to edit stuff like that

Comment: the main amsmath documentation `texdoc amsmath` has a section (3.1) on single line equations where it says to use `\[` or `equation*` (which are the same thing)

Comment: @daleif I'm okay with that. I also think your use cases might be quite different from mine. While I appreciate the advise, I would also like to focus the discussion on the question. That's partly my fault, I'll edit the question to focus better on what's important here.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you, got it. I think I did you that at some point but found that it doesn't let me use `\raisetag` anymore so I switched the equation to a gather env.

Comment: I deleted some comments following your edit:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks. I've also replaced gather with equation. I see that I can't use raisetag here either. I'm still interested how I could --- should I open a new question for this or does it fit here?

Comment: This isn't automatic, but instead of a blank line, you can put a line containing only a `%`.  That gives a similar open visual effect without the `\par` problem.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks, I'm aware of that. The problem is that it's more to type and that it breaks Vim's paragraph motion.

Comment: @danijar -- Please ask a new question about `\raisetag`.  If you can include an image as well as example code, that would be helpful; I'm not able to run latex easily at the moment, but I know this situation pretty well, and can often diagnose what's happening from looking at code + output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend *not* doing this but you can put a normal space at the ends of lines instead of `^M` so it never generates a `\par`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\eq}{\begingroup\endlinechar=32 \eqx}
\newcommand{\eqx}[1]{\endlinechar=32 \begin{gather}\begin{aligned}#1\end{aligned}\end{gather}\endgroup}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\eq{
z &= f(y) \\
y &= f(x) \\

x &= 5
}
\end{document}
```